# Variable hoisting in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading something on `Variable Hoisting` that I am not able understand exactly how to learn around it. I read W3C schools for the explanation. But, based on the sample code, I could not make what is hoisting.

code 1 [This is the code from w3c school]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var x = 5; // Initialize x
    var y;     // Declare y

    elem = document.getElementById("demo"); // Find an element 
    elem.innerHTML = x + " " + y;           // Display x and y

    y = 7;     // Assign 7 to y

    </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

But the above code still displays `'undefined'` for the variable `y`.

If I change the code as follows then it works fine. But, this below code is usual and not the different one to understand `'hoisting'`

```
<script>
var x = 5;  // Initialize x
var y;
y = 7;
elem = document.getElementById("demo"); // Find an element 
elem.innerHTML = x + " " + y;           // Display x and y
</script>
```

Any help on this to understand 'Variable hoisting'?

Comment: `y = 7;` would *not* be hoisted in this setup because it is already declared with `var y;` at the top of the function.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the W3Schools explanation, [MDN has a good example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: this is a comprehensive explanation of variable and function Hoisting.        http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Note: I've added a brief discussion of ES2015's `let` and `const` at the end of this answer.)

Fundamentally, what variable hoisting means is that no matter where you see `var` in any given scope, it's *as though* it were at the very beginning of the scope. So these are all **identical**:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 42;
}

function foo() {
    var a;
    a = 42;
}

function foo() {
    a = 42;
    var a;
}

function foo() {
    var a;
    a = 42;
    var a;
}
```

They're processed by the JavaScript engine as though they were:

```
function foo() {
    var a;
    a = 42;
}
```

Here's an example actually using variable hoisting, and also giving an example of what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*:

```js
function foo() {
    a = 42;
    b = 67;

    console.log(a); // 42
    console.log(b); // 67

    var a;
}
foo();
console.log(typeof a); // undefined
console.log(typeof b); // number?!
console.log(b);        // 67?!
```

Why does `b` exist outside of `foo`? Because inside `foo`, these two lines do **very** different things:

```
a = 42;
b = 67;
```

The first line sets the **local** variable `a`, because we declared it. Yes, we declared it *later*, but we declared it.

The second line creates an implicit global variable `b`, because we never declared `b` anywhere in `foo`.

More *(on my blog)*:

- [Poor, misunderstood `var`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

---

ES2015 (aka "ES6") introduced `let` and `const`. They're handled slightly differently from `var`:

1. They have block scope rather than function or global scope.
2. The *declaration* is hoisted to the top of the block, but they don't get any default value at that point; they get initialized (with `undefined` or the value you provide) only when the declaration is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code.

Demonstrating point #1 (block scope):

```
function foo() {
    {
        let a = 1;
        console.log(a); // 1
    }
    console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
}
foo();
```

Demonstrating point #2: This would work with `var`, it *doesn't* work with `let`:

```
function foo() {
    a = 42; // ReferenceError: a is not defined
    let a;
}
foo();
```

The time between when the identifier is reserved (declaration) and when you can use it (initialization) is called the *Temporal Dead Zone* within which you can't use the variable.

Comment: I’d like to add that variables appear to only be hoisted in `function` scope. An `x = 2;` at the top of the entire `script` actually creates a global variable bound to the `window` object (`window.x` is defined). In `function` scope however `window.x` would not be defined if `x = 2;` is on top and `var x;` comes later.

Comment: @Xufox: `var` hoisting is exactly the same at global scope as at function scope. Even at global scope, if there's a `var x;` anywhere, an `x = ...` before it will assign to that variable. That variable is also a global, but it's not the same kind of global as you'd get if there were no `var x` (but still an `x = ...` somewhere). Bizarre but true; you can delete non-`var` globals with `delete`; you can't delete `var` globals at all.

Comment: But there’s no difference between `<script>x = 3; console.log(window.x) /* 3 */; var x;</script>` and `<script>x = 3; console.log(window.x) /* 3 */;</script>` whereas there _is_ a difference between `<script>(function(){x = 3; console.log(window.x) /* undefined */; var x;})();</script>` and `<script>(function(){x = 3;console.log(window.x) /* 3 */;})();</script>`.

Comment: @Xufox: Yes, there is. It has nothing to do with whether `var` hoisting is special in global scope, though (it isn't). It has to do with the fact that assigning to unbound symbols within a function in loose mode creates an implicit global.

Comment: I see; so considering the example with `x` and `y` in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9gsypL8/3/) I’m not able to see any effect of hoisting until I try to `delete` it?

Comment: @Xufox: There's another difference: What happens if you try to use them before assigning to them. With `x`, you'd get the value `undefined`. With `y`, you'd get a `ReferenceError`: http://jsfiddle.net/f9gsypL8/4/

Answer (score 3):

Javascript Engine will execute code in two phases

1. Pre processing phase(or instantiation phase).
2. Execution Phase.

**Pre processing phase(or instantiation phase)-**
In Preprocessing phase, the script is scanned completely for all the declarations.
var - is the identifier to declare a variable.
So when var identifier is encountered, variable will be declared in the global scope.
The value of the variable is - **undefined**

**Execution Phase-**
In Execution Phase, the script is executed line by line. All the initializations will be done in this phase.

**Example-1**

For Below code snippet,
In Pre processing phase, Javascript engine will scan through the code line by line, when it encounters line "var a", it will declare variable a in the global scope.

In the Execution phase, at line "a=10", variable 'a' will be initialized with value 10. when it encounters console statements, value 10 will be printed.

```js
a=10;
console.log(a); // 10
var a;
console.log(a); // 10
```

This is how variable hoisting works.

Comment: nicely explained !

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, `var x = 21;` is broken into 2 parts: `var x;` and `x = 21;`.

The `var x;` part is *always* hoisted to the beginning of the enclosing `function`.  The `x = 21;` part is left in its original place.

The same thing happens with `function () {}` declarations - this would be hoisted to the top of the enclosing function scope:

```
function pie () {
    return 21;
}
```

just like the `var`.

Answer (score 0):

A variable can be used  before it is declared

JavaScript Initializations are Not Hoisted

[image]

**Function Hoisting** 
As previously mentioned, function declarations are also hoisted. However, functions that are assigned to variables are not hoisted.

See below example

**Function Declaration Overrides Variable Declaration When Hoisted**
[image]