# It seems the var deducere is a NaN and I cannot use it in math operations. Not sure about the rest of the code though

Tags: javascript

I have re-written the code and I get the same `NaN` when the `var deducere` is involved in the math operation. I have written the code according to the sugestions I received. Something I could not understant is, what is the event which triggers the function `calculateDeducere()` or it is possible to use a function like this just to store the value of a variable?

```
function calculeazaVenit() {
  var venit_brut = document.getElementById("venit_brut").value;
  var selection = document.getElementById("select1").value;
  var cas = (10.5 / 100) * venit_brut;
  var cass = (5.5 / 100) * venit_brut;
  var somaj = (0.5 / 100) * venit_brut;
  var nr_tichete = document.getElementById("nr_tichete").value;
  var val_tichete = document.getElementById("val_tichete").value;
  var tichete = nr_tichete * val_tichete;
  var impozit = (16 / 100) * (venit + tichete);
  if (venit_brut != null) {
    document.getElementById("venit_brutx").innerHTML = Math.round(venit_brut);
    document.getElementById("cas").innerHTML = Math.round(cas);
    document.getElementById("cass").innerHTML = Math.round(cass);
    document.getElementById("somaj").innerHTML = Math.round(somaj);
    document.getElementById("venitx").innerHTML = Math.round(venit);
    document.getElementById("tichete").innerHTML = Math.round(tichete);
    document.getElementById("impozit").innerHTML = Math.round(impozit);
    document.getElementById("venit_net").innerHTML = Math.round(venit_net);
  }
};


function calculateDeducere(selection, venit_brut) {
  var deducere0 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 300;
  var deducere1 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 400;
  var deducere2 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 500;
  var deducere3 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 600;
  var deducere4 = (1 - (venit_brut - 1500) / 1500) * 800;
  if (selection == 0 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
    return 300;
  }
  if (selection == 0 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
    return Math.ceil10(deducere0, 1);
  }
  if (selection == 1 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
    return 400;
  }
  if (selection == 1 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
    return Math.ceil10(deducere1, 1);
  }
  if (selection == 2 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
    return 500;
  }
  if (selection == 2 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
    return Math.ceil10(deducere2, 1);
  }
  if (selection == 3 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
    return 600;
  }
  if (selection == 3 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
    return Math.ceil10(deducere3, 1);
  }
  if (selection == 4 && venitBrut <= 1500) {
    return 800;
  }
  if (selection == 4 && venitBrut > 1500 && venitBrut <= 3000) {
    return Math.ceil10(deducere4, 1);
  }
  if (document.getElementById("btn_deducere").checked == false) {
    document.getElementById("deducerex").innerHTML = 0;
  }
  if (venit_brut > 3000) {
    return 0;
    document.getElementById("deducerex").innerHTML = Math.round(deducere);
  }
};

var deducere = calculateDeducere(selection, venit_brut)
var venit = venit_brut - (cas + cass + somaj + deducere);
var venit_net = venit - impozit + deducere;
```

Comment: What do you expect from `var deducere = Math.round(deducere)`? At that point, *deducere* is undefined so `Math.round(deducere)` returns *NaN*.

Comment: @RobG where should I place it to be able to use it in the math operation 'var venit = venit_brut - (cas + cass + somaj + deducere);' ? I'm quite new to javascript and I still cannot figur out the place of the variables in the script.

Comment: It has to get a value from somewhere ... you never assign it a value before using it's value, so how can anyone tell what you want it to be

Comment: Where does the initial value for *deducere* come from? See [*Variable hoisting in javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575151/variable-hoisting-in-javascript).

Comment: oh, and combine all the `if (venit_brut != null) {` into one!!!

Comment: @Jaromanda Thanks for taking the time to check my code. I have re-written the code according to your suggestions. I still cannot figure out why I get the NaN whenever I use deducere in math operations.

Comment: @RobG I have re-written the code but still cannot figure out why I get the NaN whenever I use deducere in math operations.

Comment: you're still using `deducere` before it's been assigned any value, inside `calculateDeducere` - oops nevermind, you use it after a return, so that will never get executed

Comment: Now you have `var deducere = calculateDeducere(selection, venit_brut)` but you aren't showing the values for *selection* and *venit_brut*. I don't know what you expect from `Math.ceil10(deducere0, 1)`, the method is *Math.ceil* and it only takes one argument, see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).

Comment: @RobG Math.ceil10(51, 1); // 60 I have taken the function from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round. venit_brut is taken from an input number html form, and selection is also taken from a drop-down list in html form. I just need to figure out what I did wrong in my code. It seems return is not the way to assign a value to the var deducere, though I got that suggestion from someone in stackoverflow community.